# calculating aim constraint Euler angle

Tags: vector, maya, calculation

I am trying to calculate an aim constraint in Maya using just math nodes.
I basically have two objects in 3d space, A & B. 'two transform matrices'

And I need to calculate the Euler angle with which I can rotate object A, so that it aims at object B always.
The third vector would be (0,1,0) world space up.

What would be the right formula to use to get the Euler angle?

I have tried different things, but I am not getting the right result.

Comment: You have the vector pointing from one object to the other, then you have the upvector. With these vectors you can calculate the normal (pointing upwards) and the binormal, the perpendicular between the direction vector and the normal. With these three vectors you can directly fill an transformation matrix without the need to use euler angles.

Comment: Thanks haggi, how would I go about that in practise then? Are there any good references on calculating those?

Comment: Get the direction vector with PointB - PointA, normalize it call it dir, then calculate the cross product to get a perpendicular vector with your up: tmpVec = cross(dir, up) then again make a cross product with the new vector normal  = cross(tmpVec, dir) and the binormal = cross(dir, normal). With these vectors you can fill a rotation matrix (not really sure which vector belongs into which row, so you will have to search for it).

Comment: Thanks Haggi, I tried caclculating those, but they all seem to end with the same result. I am not sure this is the way to go.

Comment: Maybe it could help if you show some of the code you tried so we could see if we can help. Since this is a developer community, the chance is quite high that someone is able to improve your approach.

Comment: Ah yes, well it's a bifrost script, so it's not something easy to share. But it's based on normal math, so I figured I could calculate it with the math nodes in Bifrost.